# Как Решать каптчу подобного вида (Puzzle Slider)?

Tags: captcha, puzzle

Есть Пазл Каптча.
Хотел узнать какие сервисы либо продукты (нейронная сеть) могут решать каптчу такого рода.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обучайте сети, если данные есть. Готовые в открытом доступе вряд ли найдёте

Comment: Хотел использовать связку Python + OpenCV  -  [ссылка](https://opencv.org/) - Как думаете насчет такого решения ? Если имели дело с такой связкой

Comment: Разрешаю использовать :). Главное, чтобы данные для обучения были. А как картинку вырезать не так важно

Comment: че там как, решил?

Answer (score 0):

Для таких каптч есть API, подсчитывающий расстояние для сдвига rapidapi.com/dyuvarov/api/slider-captcha-solver-geetest-tencent